# How to run bitcoind and lnd on separate machines on the same network

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, network, lightning-network-daemon

I have a bitcoin full node running on a raspberry pi 3b but it doesn't have enough memory to also run lnd at the same time so I'm trying to do that on a separate machine connected to the same network. I've read that this is possible but when I try to get it going I get this error:

[image: error]

It seems that the problem is when lnd tries to run getblockhash it can't talk to the machine running bitcoind. Any ideas how to make this work would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs, your lnd is trying to access the bitcoind RPC interface at the default `http://localhost:8332`, which only works if you have bitcoind running on the same machine. For a remote instance you will need to set the config option `bitcoind.rpchost` in your `lnd.conf` file to the IP address of the machine running bitcoind (see [sample-lnd.conf](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/cf9a9864cf253dbbcac5904d360bbbde763e1ebe/sample-lnd.conf#L594)). Additionally, if you haven't already, you will need to setup RPC authentication (options `bitcoind.rpcuser` and `bitcoind.rpcpass`).

Comment: This seems to have solved the error that was coming up so thank you, but now it just gets stuck at `2022-08-29 17:08:00.596 [INF] CHRE: Primary chain is set to: bitcoin` and then eventually times out. Any more ideas?